# É correto usar métodos get/set e outros, no model do laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, model

Exemplo:

No model:

```
public function getProduct()
{
  return $this->where('price',100)->get();
}

public function checkProduct($price)
{
  if($price > 100){
     return $price;
  }
}
```

No controller:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->getProduct();
$product->checkProduct();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

não é incorreto, mas existem maneiras que o próprio eloquent entrega:

- o seu primeiro exemplo `getPoduto` deveria ter um contexto melhor de nome talvez (estou imaginando que está usando o model "Produto") ... digamos peloPreco e então usar um scope em seu model:

```php
public function peloPrecoScope($query, $preco = 100) {
   return $query->where('preco', 100);
}
```

Desta forma você usaria assim:

```php
$produto = Produto->peloPreco(200)->first(); // ou get - aqui estou pegando o primeiro registro apenas do retorno
```

E sim, o check provavelmente seria como você especificou.

Veja nada impede que use como descreveu, frequentemente tenho situações onde preciso que o retorno serja "duro" (hard coded) com um método get, mas frequentemente implementar a opção de filtros no modelo usando scopes é a saída que entrega mais reuso de código e melhor compreensão de leitura do mesmo.

Para entender melhor os scopes veja na documentação: [Eloquent - Query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Caramba, ajudou bastante. Obrigado. Cheguei nessa pergunta, porque estou desenvolvendo um pequeno sistema na empresa em que trabalho, nada complexo, porém mesmo sem ser um programador avançado, sabia que colocar as interações com o banco de dados nos controllers me daria dor de cabeça se eu precisasse mudar alguma coisa na tabela por exemplo. Então pensei em criar metodos( o mais generico possível) dentro do model.

Comment: Que bom que direcionei para uma solução, agradeço se marcar a resposta como aceita